Forth: Use 'I' as its value with 'CHAR'
I try to use special loop variable I with [CHAR].
With this minimal example:
: ex ( -- )
    10 0 DO
    [CHAR] I EMIT
    LOOP
;

I expected '0123456789' to be printed but -obviously- I get 'IIIIIIIIII'
Is there a way to replace I with its value before [CHAR] gets executed?

No. Instead, to convert a value in the range 0-9 to the ASCII character code for the corresponding digit, add 48: I 48 + EMIT

@dave_thompson_085 I can't believe I didn't think about this! Thx.

[CHAR] X is a character literal, that is represented by a code point of "X" on the stack. The expression [CHAR] X always produces the same value on the stack.
If you want to print "1" given number 1 on the stack, you should get the code point of "1" at the first. You can do it as [char] 0 +.
So you example becomes:
: ex ( -- )
    10 0 DO
        I  [CHAR] 0 +  EMIT
    LOOP
;


Great answer! I would have accepted @dave_thompson_085's answer if he had offered one rather than a comment.
